# Getting a Wordpress widget instance from plugin

Tags: widget, wordpress

I'm currently working on the admin section of a Wordpress plugin and I need to access the instances of all of the active widgets (set in the widgets section). I've googled and googled, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Namely, my goal is to access the "title" text field of the widgets (if they have one). But I believe I need the widget instance to do so.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get_option('widget_text'); // as example...
```

see all widget_* values in options table

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE option_name LIKE 'widget_%')
```

Comment: This is correct, however allow me to expand for completeness. I saw the get_option function before and tried to use it but it wouldn't work. It was because the "classname" parameter (in the answer above the classname would be 'text'), should be in the format of "widget_{classname}" (ie. "widget_text"). But I'll also point out that the classname is actually **not** the name of the class you're working with. It's the **"classname" variable you assign the widget**. This might sound obvious but that's what lead me on a wild goose chase. Once I got that, the rest was all downhill.

Comment: I actually ended up hunting through my wp_options table in the DB. That's what lead me to this realisation.